# Not understanding path / to / folder

Tags: python

I am insure about what to do, so, if there is a file and its usage is literally csv_.py path/to/folder then what do I actually do with the file because I'm unsure.

Comment: Erm, you pass the path to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Normally "path/to/folder" is a placeholder so if the path to the folder that you actually want to work with would be for example "a/b" (folder named "b" in folder named "a" in working directory) then you put that in place of "path/to/folder"